# Index was outside the bounds of the array SQL server

Tags: sql-server

I get the following message during executing an user defined function at SQL server:

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.

I tried the solution given in the following link but did not solve
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2459027/fix-index-was-outside-the-bounds-of-the-array-smo-error-message-when-y
SQL Server versions

```
Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2218.0 (X64) 
Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 (RTM) - 10.50.1600.1
```

function code:

```
create FUNCTION [dbo].[ToGregorianDate](@pDate [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [datetime] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [PersianSQLFunctions].[UserDefinedFunctions].[ToGregorianDate]
```

the query in which i call the function is:
select dbo.ToGregorianDate(StartDate) from ProjectOutput where StartDate is not null
their are 86846 records in the table ProjectOutput

Comment: It may be you are using an array and looping through it. The loop is executing more number of times than existing number of records. E.g. array has 4 elements. Loop is executing from 0 to 4, instead it should go from 0 to 3. Maybe you should your array and loop if any.

Comment: Post the function code please.

Comment: Looks like you are trying to access an element by an index which is higher than the length of the array. Eg: If the length is your array is 3 and you are trying to access the 4th element. (arr[3]) but the maximum you can access is arr[2]

Comment: That's a *.NET error*, not a SQL Server one. So, work out which piece of .NET code is throwing this exception and, if you cannot work it out by inspection or debugging, please *put that code in your question*.

Comment: Management Studio could produce this error if it has a bug, in which case, try another tool (like `cmd`). The other possibility is that your function is a CLR function and contains a bug, in which case you'll need to find the source to it, or use a disassembler on the assembly. SQL Server itself isn't written in .NET and can't produce this error.

Comment: i use the following user defined function,                                                   create FUNCTION [dbo].[ToGregorianDate](@pDate [nvarchar](4000))
RETURNS [datetime] WITH EXECUTE AS CALLER
AS 
EXTERNAL NAME [PersianSQLFunctions].[UserDefinedFunctions].[ToGregorianDate]
GO  i call this function in a query as "select dbo.ToGregorianDate(StartDate) from ProjectOutput" after executing this it generate the above error

Comment: That's a SQL CLR function. You have an assembly called `PersianSQLFunctions` containing utility functions written in a .NET language that can be invoked from SQL. It's the code in that assembly that's generating the error, and that's what you need to find.

Comment: Share that SQL CLR code.

Comment: Cetin Basoz i find the SQL CLR code then i share that.

Comment: thanks, solved the problem was not in the code problem was in the data of ProjectOutput Table.